# Como mudar html de acordo com valor do retorno?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-datatables

Fiz a ativação tudo certo do jQuery datatable server side. Tudo funcional.

Entretanto, na primeira coluna eu retorno 1 para ativo e 0 para inativo. Eu queria que se fosse 1 (ativo), **aparece-se no lugar do número 1**:

```
<i class='ace-icon fa fa-circle green'></i>
```

**e se fosse 0**:

```
<i class='ace-icon fa fa-circle red'></i>
```

Com PHP eu fazia assim(sem a ativação server side):

```
<td class="center">
    <label class="pos-rel">
      <?php
         if ($status == 0):
            echo "<i class='ace-icon fa fa-circle red'></i>";
         elseif($status == 1):
            echo "<i class='ace-icon fa fa-circle green'></i>"; 
        else: echo "<i class='ace icon fa fa-circle orange'></i>";
endif; ?>
     </label>
</td>
```

Mas eu não sei como fazer em JAVASCRIPT para mudar de acordo com o valor do retorno. Poderiam me ajudar?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer isso com Javascript e jQuery

Note que eu defini manualmente a variavel `status` com o valor `0`, você deverá alterar se esse valor vai vir do banco de dados ou através de outra função de acordo com o que precisar.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

var status = 0;

var resposta = document.getElementById("resposta"); 

if (status == 0) {
 resposta.innerHTML = "<i class='ace-icon fa fa-circle red'></i>";
} else if (status == 1){
 resposta.innerHTML = "<i class='ace-icon fa fa-circle green'></i>";
}
else {
 resposta.innerHTML = "<i class='ace icon fa fa-circle orange'></i>";
}
});
```

```css
.green {
 color:#41B319;
}
.red {
 color:#f00;
}
.orange{
 color:#F97400;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/64f885daf6.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<td class="center">
    <label class="pos-rel">
    <div id="resposta"></div>
     </label>
</td>
```